# error c0000: syntax error, unexpected '?' at token '?'

Tags: c#, opengl, shader, vbo, opentk

Alright I searched other peoples questions and could not find a solution to my problem. I am using OpenTK in C# and GLSL 330. It is producing the error message 
error c0000: syntax error, unexpected '?' at token '?'

For some reason it doesn't like something I'm doing. So, here is my code I hope someone can tell 
me what I'm doing wrong.

```
public static string vertexShaderSource = @"
#version 330

uniform mat4 pvm;

in vec4 Position;
in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 texCoordV;

void main()
{
    texCoordV = texCoord;
    gl_Position = Position * pvm;
}";

public static string fragmentShaderSource = @"
#version 330

in vec2 texCoordV;

out vec4 colorOut;

void main()
{
    colorOut = vec4(texCoord, 0.0, 0.0);    
}";


    public void Initalize()
    {
        style = GUI_Skin.styles[0];
        vertices = new Vector3[6];
        vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0f);
        vertices[1] = new Vector3(100, 0, 0f);
        vertices[2] = new Vector3(0, 100, 0f);
        vertices[3] = new Vector3(100, 0, 0f);
        vertices[4] = new Vector3(0, 100, 0f);
        vertices[5] = new Vector3(100, 100, 0f);

        GL.GenBuffers(1, out vertHandle);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertHandle);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                               new IntPtr(vertices.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                               vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        texCoords = new Vector2[6];
        texCoords[0] = new Vector2(0,0);
        texCoords[1] = new Vector2(1, 0);
        texCoords[2] = new Vector2(0, 1);
        texCoords[3] = new Vector2(1, 0);
        texCoords[4] = new Vector2(0, 1);
        texCoords[5] = new Vector2(1, 1);

        GL.GenBuffers(1, out texHandle);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, texHandle);
        GL.BufferData<Vector2>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                               new IntPtr(texCoords.Length * Vector2.SizeInBytes),
                               texCoords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertHandle);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertHandle);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(texHandle);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, texHandle);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 6);

        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(vertHandle);
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(texHandle);
    }
```

Comment: there's usually some line/location information with errors

Comment: does this error message apear when compiling the vertex or the fragment shader?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with character encoding to me. GLSL expects a small subset of UTF-8 and will generate errors such as this if it encounters characters it doesn't expect outside of comments. If you remove the `@` and use `\n` at the end of each line instead of one long verbatim string literal, does that change anything?

Comment: Ratchet freak it says 0(13) for the line number|||||||


BDL Yes its a compiling error I probably should have mentioned|||||||||| 



Andon M. Coleman that seems to remove the error but now its just a white screen. You where correct though :)
A similar issue I had before when binding the vertex data. Probably has something to do with that.

Comment: @LeviGraham: Well, there is one other issue that I can see. `gl_Position = Position * pvm;` looks very unusual to me. Ordinarily in OpenGL, you would have something to the effect: `gl_Position = pvm * Position`. Unless your matrices are stored row-major (which is possible, as I recall there is at least one framework for C# that does this, but I don't remember which), you should consider swapping the operands.

Comment: I didn't think the order would matter. I did end up calling transpose because I didn't understand why my matrix was resulting in wrong locations.
           'code'GL.UniformMatrix4(uniformLocation, true, ref mat);'code'

Thanks for the help! I figured out where the final problem lies. In the vertex attribute pointer I wasn't providing the location for the texture coords.

           <code> int texpos = GL.GetAttribLocation(GUI_Skin.shaderProgramHandle, "texCoord");
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(texpos, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);</code>

Comment: @LeviGraham: Yes, order matters when multiplying matrices. It's a non-commutative operation unlike traditional arithmetic multiplication. You can fix the problem you were discussing one of two ways, by transposing your matrix (which you did) or reversing the order of all of the operands in the matrix multiplication. You should write an answer explaining what you did to solve your problem though, that's how Stack Overflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so the issues have been fixed. Thanks to the helpful comments above.

Lets start with the shader. The @ symbol before the string declaration had to be removed and after every line \n had to be inserted. Also, I was calling transpose when I draw with the shader. Which could be fixed by changing the order of matrices.

```
    public static void Run()
    {
        int uniformLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "pvm");
        Matrix4 mat;
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ProjectionMatrix, out mat);
        GL.UniformMatrix4(uniformLocation, false, ref mat);

        GL.UseProgram(shaderProgramHandle);
    }
```

I changed from `GL.UniformMatrix4(uniformLocation, true, ref mat);` to `GL.UniformMatrix4(uniformLocation, false, ref mat);` and in the shader itself the order of gl_Position was changed from `Position * pvm;` to `pvm * Position;`

```
public static string vertexShaderSource = "#version 330\n" +
    "uniform mat4 pvm;\n" +
    "in vec4 Position;\n" +
    "in vec2 texCoord;\n" +
    "out vec2 texCoordV;\n" +
    "void main()\n" +
    "{\n" +
        "texCoordV = texCoord;\n" +
        "gl_Position = pvm * Position;\n" +
    "}\n";

    public static string fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330\n" +
    "in vec2 texCoordV;\n" +
    "out vec4 colorOut;" +
    "void main()\n" +
    "{\n" +
        "colorOut = vec4(texCoordV, 0.0, 0.0);\n" +
    "}\n" ;
```

After this was fixed I was getting an error where the rendering surface went white. The error was located within the `Draw()` function. Basically I wasn't assigning the array locations properly.

```
public void Draw()
    {
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertHandle);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, texHandle);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 6);

        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    }
```

Comment: If you've answered your own question correctly before anyone else has, accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I don't really know what your talking about but i'm guessing its the check mark.

Comment: Looks like you found it.